# Why does BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher stop firing `Received` events?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy

WPF app using BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher will eventually stop receiving advertisement data and appears to be in a bad state.

Windows 10 Pro 1809 build 17763.292.
WPF app using Win 10 native apis via this winmd file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\Windows.winmd`

It takes between 1-7 hours to trigger the bad state, but it always happens eventually.

After getting in the bad state, the "System" process shows high CPU usage.

Found something that seems to describe the same behavior but is on a raspberry pi: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/812

Reproducible with this repo: https://github.com/jeremywho/win10testingAdWatcher

Here's the code used around `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel> Devices { get; } = new ObservableCollection<DeviceViewModel>();
    private readonly BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher _watcher;
    private object _locker = new object();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher {ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active};
        _watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
        _watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;

        _watcher.Start();
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} [{sender.Status}] [{sender.GetHashCode()}] stopped called");
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName)) return;

        var timestamp = eventArgs.Timestamp;
        var advertisementType = eventArgs.AdvertisementType;
        var rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm;
        var localName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;

        Debug.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] [{timestamp}] [{localName}] [{rssi}] [{advertisementType}]");

        lock(_locker)
        {
            var foundDevice = Devices.FirstOrDefault(d => d.BluetoothAddress == eventArgs.BluetoothAddress.ToString());
            if (foundDevice != null)
            {
                foundDevice.LastSeen = timestamp.ToString();
                return;
            }
        }

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                var device = new DeviceViewModel(eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName, eventArgs.BluetoothAddress, timestamp);
                Devices.Add(device);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably memory issue. If you do not mind you can try our [Bluetooth Framework](https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm). There is Beacons demo that does what you need.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and can repro it on 3 machines. (Same windows version)
Once I try to restart I get a blue screen. It does looks like a driver issue.

Comment: I have tried it now using a UWP test app. It fails with the same result (Win 10 1809). So I think we can rule out using the UWP SDK within .net causes this error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a known bug in Windows 10 (1809 maybe earlier too) that can happen if you run an "active scan".

> Yes your application can cause this behavior, if you're application results in the OS doing an "active scan". Are you using DeviceWatcher and if so can you share the query you're application is using?
>
> We are also looking at mitigations on our side, we have one in the latest 19H1 release. While active scans are not recommended for extended durations if you join Windows Insiders and choose the option that contains "active development".

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/274e5d96-d21d-490d-8c8b-934a41239f88/windows-100177631-microsoftbluetoothlegacyleenumeratorsys-stuck-in-its-deviced0entry-routine?forum=wdk